# Specializing a template class member function for only one type

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a template class that has lots of functions but is essentially a vector class.  I want to add one function to just the bool type.

```
#include <vector>
template <typename T>
class reflected{
    private:
        T*dev_;
        T*host_;
        ar_size size;
        reflected<T>& operator=(reflected<T>& rhs);//do not impliment.  assign not allowed.
        reflected( reflected<T>& old);  //do not impliment. Copy not allowed.
    public:
        reflected():size(0L),dev_(NULL),host_(NULL){}
        reflected(ar_size n):size(n),dev_(NULL),host_(NULL){init();}
        reflected(const T*x,ar_size n):size(n),dev_(NULL),host_(NULL){init();set(x);}
        ~reflected();
        void init();
        void init(ar_size n);
        void init(const T*x,ar_size n);
        void set(const T * x);
        void setat(ar_index i, T x);
        const T getat(ar_size i);
        const T * devPtr();
        const T operator [](const ar_index i);
        ar_size length(){return size;}
};
```

I want to add a function `vector<ar_index> reflected<bool>::which()` to the special case of the reflected class, which is the only case where it would make sense.  What is the best way to do this.  the compiler seems to not like adding which() to reflected and only defining it for bool.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define it in the class template like this

```
template <typename T> struct id { typedef T type; };

template <typename T>
class reflected{
    private:
        /* ... */
        vector<ar_index> which(id<bool>) { 
          /* ... */
        }
    public:
        /* ... */
        vector<ar_index> which() { return which(id<T>()); }
};
```

This gives a compile time error if you call `which` on a `reflected<T>` for whose `T` you haven't given the proper definition.

Comment: I'm not sure if he/she wants the method to fail or simply that it is not defined *but for* `bool`. Anyway, your solution is very nice :)

Comment: How does that compare to John Dibling answer ? Is there any advantage provided by the additional 'indirection' ? Thanks

Comment: @icecrime you don't need to duplicate constructors and it scales. If some function makes only sense for `int` and not for others, you don't need another derived class. I like to use overloading for this.

Comment: @Johannes sorry, I was referring to John Dibling answer which does not rely on inheritance but on a `which()` method only defined for `reflected<bool>` specialization

Comment: @icecrime Oh sorry, I misread :) John's does not give compile time errors. It will later fail to link (which can be much later for a big program).

Comment: It should also be noted that his solution only works if all parameters, including the ones of any nesting templates, are known (that's the case here, but might not be in all your templates). So if your class had two parameters and you want to provide it only for the pair `<bool, T>` or if you have one parameter and want to provide it for all pointers (`<T*>`), you can't use @John's way. If you use overloading, you just make a `template<typename U> vector<ar_index> which(id<T*>) { ... }`.

Comment: @Johannes ooooh right, I haven't thought about that ! Thanks :)

Comment: This is awesome.  Love it.  Worked without breaking my code, or making me rewrite the entire class.  Thank you.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That's a really elegant technique. I wonder how I would have to tweak it to fit something like `reflected<bool, T>`, if `reflected` was a class template with two parameters types

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add just one question, you can combine inheritance with specialization:

```
template <typename T>
class reflected_base { 
    // your current 'reflected' contents go here
}; 

template <typename T>
class reflected : public reflected_base { };

template <>
class reflected<bool> : public reflected_base {
    vector<ar_index> which();
};
```

The downside of this approach is that you have to reimplement certain operations (destructors, copy constructors, etc.) for each specialization.  Another option would be:

```
template <typename T>
class specialized_reflected { };

template <>
class specialized_reflected<bool> {
public:
    vector<ar_index> which();
};

template <typename T>
class reflected : public specialized_reflected<T> {
    // your current 'reflected' contents go here
};
```

Though, then there are potential issues with dependent name lookup.  A third option (and probably the one I would choose) would be to use a non-member function:

```
vector<ar_index> which(reflected<bool>&);
```

Comment: `+1` for beating me by 90secs!

Comment: You need `<T>` for reflected_base also in the declaration of reflected. But then, why do you exactly need the reflected_base?

Comment: @Diego:  So that the primary `reflected` template and each of the specializations of `reflected` can all use the same members.

Comment: That said, Johannes's answer is far superior (as usual...)

Comment: @James: But this can be done by just adding the desired function to the specialization `reflected<bool>`...

Comment: @Diego:  You'd have to define all of the member functions for the primary template and for each specialization.

Comment: @Diego:  On second thought, I took the OP's request literally ("how can I add a member function to just one specialization?"), whereas Johannes and John both gave good answers for how the OP's desired result (or at least what is probably the OP's desired result) can be achieved much more simply.

Comment: @James: Fair enough. I also like their answers :) And also you're right the base class helps in not duplicating code.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done directly the way you want.  But you can achieve a similar result by not defining `reflected()` for any class except the specialized one.  Then you will get a liner error if you try to use it on a non-supported class.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

template<typename A>
class Gizmo
{
public:
    Gizmo(){};
    int which();    
};

template<> int Gizmo<bool>::which()
{
    return 42;
}

int main()
{

    Gizmo<bool> gb;
    gb.which();

    Gizmo<int> gi;
    gi.which(); // LINKER ERROR for Gizmo<int>which()

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: snap! but I would describe this as " adding which() to reflected and only defining it for bool." which is what the OP says he was doing.

Comment: I interpreted OP's description as if her were trying to redefine the class for a `bool` specialization.

Comment: After re-reading you may be right.  If OP responds that this is what he was doing, I'll delete it.

Comment: This is what I was trying, it wasn't working the compiler did not like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `vector<ar_index> reflected<bool>::which()` to `reflected<bool>` (and only to it, not to the general template). If you get an error, maybe you're not doing the template specialization correctly...